# GetCalendarExporter() call is missing when called on Olk::MAPIFolderPtr

Tags: c++, outlook, com, outlook-addin, mapi

I want to set the CalendarDetail property of CalendarSharing object.

Found the below link where we can set it using Outlook Object Model - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.calendarsharing

I have written the below code in my C++ add-in. Where can not see the method `GetCalendarExporter()`, its missing :( I am calling it on `Olk::MAPIFolderPtr`.
What is wrong here? How to set the above property?

```
CComPtr<Olk::_NameSpace> spNameSpace;
GetMapiNameSpace((LPVOID *)&spNameSpace);
Olk::MAPIFolderPtr calendarFolder = spNameSpace->GetDefaultFolder(Olk::OlDefaultFolders::olFolderCalendar);
calendarFolder->GetCalendarExporter() **// Not able to see this method**
```

Comment: Do you see the method in Outlook VBA editor?

Answer (score 0):

That means you have old headers. Recreate the Outlook Object Model tlh file.

Comment: Hi Dmitry,

I have got below microsoft link to generate the tlh files. Using below mentioned import statement to generate files. Is this the right way to generate files?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-outlook-2010-using-c-with-mfc

#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\mso.dll" named_guids

#import "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSOUTL.OLB" no_namespace rename("Folder", "OlkFolder") rename("CopyFile", "OlkCopyFile") rename("GetOrganizer", "GetOrganizerAE")

Comment: Instead of hadrcoding the path, you can import by clsid `#import "libid:00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"`

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for quick response. That solve the issue.